# End of the Month file not running the last day certain months

Tags: bash, shell

We have a shell scripts which gets triggered via cron on the last day of each  month, on certain months the script fails to run. My attempt is to figure out where the issue may possibly lie.

The crontab line look:

```
5 0 * * * /root/mount_monthly_file.sh
```

Here's the whole script, at the top we specify dates and below you'll see clean ups. All in all the script is meant to present two files from the day before via mounts:

```
#!/bin/bash

SERVICEDATE=`date +%Y%m`
EXPIREDDATE=`date +%Y%m -d "last month"`
SOURCEPATH="/mnt/aws_sg01/refdata/1/refdata/lse/"
SERVICEPATH="/srv/latest/refdata/lse/"
DATENOW=`date +%-d`
PREVMONTHLASTDAY=`date +%Y%m%d -d "\`date +%Y%m01\` -1 day"`
PREVMONTHRETENTION=3 # how many days into the current month to keep last day of prev month's file
```

Comment: That crontab entry will run the script every day. Is there something in the script that prevents it from running except on the last day of the month, and if so what is that code? Also, which months doesn't it run on?

Comment: Hi Gordon, the script failed to run this morning and had to be triggered manually. Previously it has failed to fun on: 2022-04-01 and 2022-06-01 ((YYYY-MM-DD). Rest of the script is mostly just clean up jobs, I'm adding the whole script to the top of the thread.

Comment: I thought you said it ran on the last day of each month, but those are the *first* days of months.

Comment: You might consider Airflow as a better replacement for cron.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, sorry I should have been more specific. The system creates 2 files in /srv/latest/refdata/lse/...tar.gz and then mounts them from /mnt/aws_sg01/refdata/1/refdata/lse/...tar.gz The files for the day before, are presented the following day. So the date for 30th of June should be presented this morning (1st of July) via those mounts.

Comment: You say the cronjob only runs on the last day of the month but your crontab says to run at 5 minutes after midnight every day.

Comment: You say "the script failed to run this morning". How do you know? (eg. Perhaps it is still running.)

Answer (score 0):

Will run another cron with 0 5 1 * * for the script before migrating it over to Airflow as suggested by Kamil.